# javascript form using POST method

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, post

I wanna post with javascript and I have 3 datas.

How can I post 3 value with this form of javascript?

```
                        dateval = $('#tarih input.datepicker').val();
                        hourval = $('#scheduleHour').val();
                        minuteval = $('#scheduleMinute').val();

                        var form = document.createElement("form");
                        form.setAttribute("method", "post");
                        form.setAttribute("action", "/app/" + @appId + "/volumes/" + obj.data("rowid") + "/scheduledPublish");
                        var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
                        hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
                        hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "dateval");
                        hiddenField.setAttribute("value", result);
                        form.appendChild(hiddenField);
                        document.body.appendChild(form);
                        form.submit();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'post',
    url: 'http://some.com/services/service.php',
    data: { date: dateval, hour: hourval, minute: minuteval },
    success: function (data) {
        //response..
    }
});
```

Comment: I need to use form. dateval, hourval and minuteval are my datas.

Answer (score 0):

Post like this;

```
    var form = document.createElement("form");
    form.setAttribute("method", "post");
    form.setAttribute("action", "/app/" + @appId + "/volumes/" + obj.data("rowid") + "/scheduledPublish");

    var hiddenField = document.createElement("input");
    hiddenField.setAttribute("type", "hidden");
    hiddenField.setAttribute("name", "dateval");
    hiddenField.setAttribute("value", dateval);
    form.appendChild(hiddenField)
```

and get from java like this;

```
    form.data().get("name value");
```